# Prove: $ 4 \nmid (n-2)^2 \ \Rightarrow \ 6 \nmid n \ \ \ ,n \in \Bbb Z $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How should I prove this theorem? What method of proof should I use?

$ 4 \nmid (n-2)^2 \ \Rightarrow \ 6 \nmid n \ \ \  ,n \in \Bbb Z   $

Comment: $2$ does not divide $n-2$ i.e. $n-2$ is not even therefore $n$ is not even and not divisible by $6.$

Comment: $4\nmid (n-2)^2\iff 2\nmid n-2\iff n$ is odd.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Try proving the contrapositive, i.e.

If $6 \mid n$, then $4 \mid (n-2)^2$

Answer (score 2):

HINT: $4 \not\mid (n-2)^2 \Rightarrow 2\not\mid(n-2) \Rightarrow (n-2)$ is odd i.e. $n$ is odd.

So $6\not\mid n$